# BehaviorTracking tag for clickContentEvent not working

Tags: content-management-system, weblogic, portal, websphere-portal, weblogic12c

I am facing tough time for clickContentEvent BehaviorTracking tag to fire and insert an entry into bt_event table.
But displayContentEvent is working fine without any issues.

I have settings in Portal Administration for Event Service and Behaviour Tracking Service correctly.

com.bea.p13n.tracking.listeners.BehaviorTrackingListener and ClickContentEvent is configured.

This is my JSP that is trying to retrive content and when I click the link, its not inserting for clickContentEvent.

```
<pz:contentSelector rule="testcontent" id="nodes" sortBy="cm_nodeName desc"/>
 <utility:notNull item="<%=nodes%>">
 <utility:forEachInArray array="<%=nodes%>" id="node" type="com.bea.content.Node">

<BehaviorTracking:clickContentEvent documentId="<%=node.getName() %>" id="eventInfo"/>
<% String url = request.getContextPath() + "/ShowBinary"+node.getPath()+"?"+ eventInfo; %>
<a href="<%= url %>" ><%=node.getName() %> </a>
</utility:forEachInArray>
</utility:notNull>
```

And I have the following Servlet mapping in web.xml -

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ClickThroughEventFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.bea.p13n.tracking.clickthrough.ClickThroughEventFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ClickThroughEventFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/ShowBinary/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I am confused when displayContentEvent is working, why not this clickContentEvent?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the server and now its working.